# How to compute gradient of cumprod safely

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, derivative

I'm trying to write a `cumprod` Op for a deep learning framework, the forward computation is simple, however there's some trouble with gradient computation.

Apparently, **both** [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3862) and [Theano](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/5197) are using the following *bugged* implementation :

```
def cumprod_grad(x, g):
    '''
    Returns cumprod gradient wrt x

    Args:
        x: vector
            original input
        g: vector
            upstream gradient
    '''
    fx = np.cumprod(x)
    return np.cumsum((fx*g)[::-1])[::-1] / x
```

This works most times, however in case `x` has an element of zero, the division will generate `nan`, which is incorrect.

Example:

```
x = np.array([1,0])
y = np.cumprod(x) # [1,0]
delx = cumprod_grad(x, np.array([1,1]))
# the correct delx is [1,1], however the output is [1, nan]
```

An **O(n^2)** fix is straightforward, however it's inefficient.

What would a efficient and vectorizable solution for this problem? Preferably an O(n) solution suitable for GPU implementation.

Comment: So, if `x == 0`,  what must happen with that division part : `/ x`? Look into `np.where` maybe to switch cases.

Comment: Are you talking about [this bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3862)?

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, exactly.